# $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1-nt ~;~ 0 \le t \le \frac1n$. Error in this approach?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1-nt ~;~ 0 \le t \le \dfrac  {1}{n}$.

**Attempt:**

Since, $ 0 \le t \le \frac  {1}{n} \implies t = \frac {1}{kn}$ for some $ k \in \mathbb Z^+$.

$\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1-nt = 1- n.\dfrac {1}{kn} = 1-  \dfrac {1}{k}$

which means : $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(z)=g(z)= \begin{cases}
       1-  \dfrac {1}{k}  ~~~;~~t \in (0,1], k \in \mathbb Z^+;\\
       1  ~~~;~~t =0\\
     \end{cases}$

> But, my book says that $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(z)=g(z)= \begin{cases}
>        0  ~~~;~~t \in (0,1];\\
>        1  ~~~;~~t =0\\
>      \end{cases}$

Where could be the error? Thanks!

Comment: If $k\in [0,1]$ then $$t=\frac{1}{kn}\ge \frac{1}{n}$$ Also, you should write explicitly your question.

Comment: $k \in \mathbb Z^+$

Comment: Actually, you need $k\in [1,\infty)$. If I understand correctly, you have $$f_n(t)=1-nt, \quad t\in \left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$$ and you want to find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(t)$.

Comment: thats affirmative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're both right; the question is bad.

Suppose $t > 0$. $t$ cannot be fixed because then for some large $n$ we would have $t > \frac{1}{n}$, which is stipulated not to be the case. So $t$ must have some dependence on $n$. However, the dependence is not given.

The book assumes the dependence is follows. Given $t_0 > 0$, $t = \max\{t_0, \frac{1}{n}\}$.

You assume the dependence is $t = \frac{1}{kn}$.

There are other possible dependences, and they will give different answers for the limit.

Comment: Great answer! (+1)